# дубликат элементов после перезапуска

Tags: python, tkinter

С основного окна вызываю довернее окно tkinter, в нем в цикле добавляю кнопки, после закрытия его (не основного), и снова вызов открытия с главного, почему-то остались кнопки с прошлого раза и тем самым происходит дубляж.
Код дочернего окна:

```
from tkinter import *

def closes():
    window.destroy()

window = Toplevel()

names = [] 

for i in range(2):
    names.append('widjet'+str(i))

for j in range(2):
    names[j] = Button(window, text='button'+str(j), command=closes).grid(row=j, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Код дочернего и основго окна находятся в разных скриптах, по логике закрытия скрипта с дояерним, должны стерется все данные, но этогш не происходит.

Upd:
Вопрос решен. Оказывается, я не знал, что при старте обращаютмя ко всем глобальным переменным во всех используемых скриптах, и после вызова скрипта к ней уже не происходит обращение, от того и сохранялись данные. Глобальные переменные нужно самому обнулять если таковое требуется.

Comment: Покажите где у вас основное окно, где дочернее? "С основного окна вызываю довернее окно tkinter" Каким образом это происходит? Можете расставить комментарии пошагово?

Comment: Вообще в описании написано, что представлен код дочернего окна, в котором и происходит баг. Код основного окга не нужен, так там одна к нопка, при нажатии которой просто вызывается второй скрипт с дочергим окном.

Comment: А ну тогда сам себе помоги.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать проверить наличие экземпляров виджетов с помощью функции .winfo_exists(). Эта функция проверяет существование виджетов.
https://progler.ru/blog/python-winfo-ismapped-i-winfo-exists-v-tkinter здесь подробнее

Comment: Во-первых, дочернее окно в отдельном скрипте и имена кнопок я не сохраняю отдельно перед закрытие окна. Во-вторых мне нет смысла проверять сущетсвует старая кнопка или нет, так как ее не должно быть вообще, кроме новых которые создаются при открытии скрипта с окном.